# How large buffer do I need?

Tags: c, printf, c89

For a double value stored in *x*, how large does *buffer* need to be in the function call below?

```
sprintf(buffer, "%.*g", DBL_DIG, x);
```

Comment: doesn't it somehow depend on `DBL_DIG`?

Comment: To avoid buffer overflows, use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead.

Comment: Surely you can read `C11 7.21.6.1 /8` as well as _we_ can.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Of course it depends on DBL_DIG, *buffer* needs a declaration like `char buffer[DBL_DIG + ?]`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and paxdiablo I use (ANSI) C89.

Comment: Perhaps `DBL_DIG+1`?

Comment: Although I don't see much point in using `g` with `.*`

Comment: @dmg `DBL_DIG` only specifies the maximum number of decimals. I also need room for the integer part, the decimal separator, an `e` and the exponent.

Comment: @dmg Without the `.*` I get less precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The worst case will be :

- one minus `-` if number if negative
- one decimal point `.`
- DBL_DIG decimal digits
- the exponent part that should not be greater that `e+999` (*)
- the terminating null

So the size of buffer should be `DBL_DIG + 8`.

(*) According to wikipedia page on [IEEE floating point] the exponent part for a double is at most 2<sup>1023</sup> < 10<sup>308</sup>. So the decimal representation of the exponent need at most 3 digits.

Of course above stuff only has sense for IEEE754 compliant floating point implementations (thanks to  Basile Starynkevitch for noticing)

Comment: So the digit before the decimal point is accounted for by DBL_DIG?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom As far as I know yes. All my tests confirmed that.

Comment: IMHO, an (hypothetical) C89 implementation might not be IEEE754 compliant (e.g. some C implementation on IBM/3090 mainframe)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : you are absolutely right ! I'll add the precision in my answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can anything be said about the maximum number of digits in the exponent in such a non IEEE 754 implementation? Is there an upper limit of `sizeof(double)`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll better use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` ; I would guess that the following could be (almost always) safe

```
char buf[32+2*DBL_DIG];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%.*g", DBL_DIG, x);
```

or simply perhaps `char buf[48];`

I am surprized you are asking. Why do you care that much?

BTW, most C (but in principle not all) implementations use [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). See the [floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de).

Comment: I can't use `snprintf` since I use C89. Where do the "magic" numbers 32 and 2 come from? The reason I "care that much" is that I want to reconstruct a double literal value read by the scanner in my compiler project.